# asp.net mvc 5 should server side validation run if client side runs first

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I have a validation attribute class that runs server side that checks a form text box. I also implemented it client side in a javascript call. My question is, if the client side gets called and returns true, should the server side get called as well? Should both client side and server side be called? It seems like if the client side validation passes then there would be no need to call any kind of validation again on server side. It just seems a little redundant to check something twice.

Answer (score 4):

Client-side validation is for convenience. Server-side validation is the real validation. You should never trust the client, anyway, so you should run the server-side validation in any case.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It absolutely should.

The reason is because what if someone circumvents your website and makes calls direct to your server? What if they try and put bad data in to break your site? Without the server side validation too you're leaving yourself unprotected.

The reason for clientside validation is so you can provide feedback to the user quickly to fix mistakes, possibly even as they type without needing postbacks.

The reason for server side validation is to provide more complex validation which might involve database lookups and most importantly protect your server from malicious users.

Comment: It just seems like there should be a way of checking if client side validation was called and if passed then don't run server side validation.

Comment: @user1186050 How would the server know? The client would have to tell it, right? And since the client is out of the server's control, the server can be easily lied to.

Comment: @user1186050: Just to note if one of the answers helped you then you should accept it as the answer. If not then feel free to ask for more detail through comments of by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

client-side validation is just a way of reducing the work force of your server-side because once the client-side validation is true, it will be true in server-side application. sometimes, people might by-pass client-side validation which your server-side validation will help you on that. It best to always do server-side validation but just to reduce request to your server all the times for validation, client-server can help you confirm first before request go to server and if it false, no request go to server-side.